# If $L$ is a closed convex subset of compact convex set $K$, then the restriction map $A(K)\to A(L)$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, convex-analysis, transformation, affine-geometry

For a convex set $X$ denote by $A(X)$ the set of continuous affine functions on $X$.

Let $L$ be a closed convex subset of compact Hausdorff convex set $K$, then I want to show that the restriction map $A(K)\to A(L)$ is surjective.

If we just considered continuous functions, then the restriction map $C(K)\to C(L)$ is really a surjective homomorphism (one can use for example Tietze extension Theorem).

Thanks for any help

Comment: What makes you think that the extension by zero $g$ is affine or continuous? Try something simple, e.g. $X=\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @A.Γ. $X=\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. It works for continuous functions, if $Y\subseteq X$ is a closed subset and $X$ is compact, the restriction map $C(X)\to C(Y)$ is a homomorphism

Comment: Just pick compact $K$ and $L$. Conclusion: $g(x)=0$ outside $L$ does not work. It is not going to give you affine or even continuous function on a larger set.

Comment: @A.Γ. Sorry! of course, this does not work, but still one can extend to a continuous function on $L$, for example by Tietze extension Theorem. I will edit my question, thanks!

Comment: Right, but you need a special extension - not just to any continuous, but to a continuous *affine* function.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify the following points: (1) Is $X$ a subset of a normed linear space $V$ or of a more general topological vector space? (2) What is the precise definition of an affine map on a conxex set $K$? Simply the restriction of an affine map $f : V  \to \mathbb{R}$ to $K$?

Comment: The problem is not that trivial as it may sound. In general, to have the extension property required one needs [extra conditions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02762617).